# Is there a way in Scalding Type Safe API to mapWithValue with two or more ValuePipes?

Tags: scalding

Using Scalding, Type Safe API, this code works, where `dictForKeys` and `dictForValues` are both `ValuePipe[Map[String,String]]`:

```
SomeKeyValueTypedPipe
  .mapWithValue(dictForKeys) { case ((key, value), dictForKeys) =>
       (dictForKeys.get.getOrElse(key, key), value) }
  .mapWithValue(dictForValues) { case ((key, value), dictForValues) =>
       (key, dictForValues.get.getOrElse(value, value)) }
```

I was just wondering whether there's a more compact way of writing this, i.e. use only 1 mapWithValue step with 2 separate ValuePipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a ValuePipe of a tuple of Maps, like `ValuePipe[(Map[String, String], Map[String, String])]`, and then use it like so:

```
SomeKeyValueTypedPipe
 .mapWithValue(dict) { case ((key, value), (dictForKeys, dictForValues)) =>
   (dictForKeys.get.getOrElse(key, key), dictForValues.get.getOrElse(value, value)) }
```